# SQL Server - Analyzing Multiple Stored Procedure Statistics

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to analyze 1000+ stored procedures and I need to find out the:

- Elapsed Time in Sec (AVG based on # of iterations)
- CPU (AVG based on # of iterations)
- Logical Reads

At first I'm using [SQL Query Stress](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2730/sql-query-stress-tool/), but it will take me so much time to test-run each stored procedure and analyzing test parameters.

So my question is, is there an easier way to get what I needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are in a live database, then you can use the DMV [`sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc280701.aspx) to pull information for all the Stored Procedures that have been run and cached on the instance.

A basic query to pull all procedures ordered by the Average Duration may look something like this:

```
USE <DATABASE>;
GO

SELECT  
  o.name, 
  deps.total_elapsed_time/CAST(deps.execution_count AS DECIMAL(10,2))/1000000 AS AvgDurationInS,
  deps.total_worker_time/CAST(deps.execution_count AS DECIMAL(10,2))/1000000 AS AvgCPUInS,
  deps.total_logical_reads/CAST(deps.execution_count AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS AvgLogicalReads,
  deps.cached_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS deps
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
  ON o.object_id = deps.object_id
WHERE deps.database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY AvgDurationInS DESC;
```

However, this doesn't show you all the queries within the Stored Procedure and break down each one by the same metrics. You can do that using [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx)

Comment: Does the sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats only store information of stored procedures that has ran and had been cached already? Because there are some stored procedures that aren't appearing when I run the query you gave.

Comment: Yes, it only stores historic information about procedures that have run